# What to do about "Block sealing failed" on a new Clique blockchain?

Tags: go-ethereum, clique

I've use puppeth to configure a test blockchain. I inited the blockchain and started geth. When I go into the console, this is the output I get:

```
> miner.start()
INFnOul l[0
6-> 09|00:30:09] Starting mining operation
INFO [06-09|00:30:09] Commit new mining work                   number=1 txs=0 uncles=0 elapsed=0s
WARN [06-09|00:30:09] Block sealing failed                     err=unauthorized
```

There's an account that's been created with a key in the keystore, and I set it up in puppeth so it would be an authorized sealer. So why is block sealing still unauthorized?

Answer (score 1):

you may need to add `--networkid 9876` for example:

`eth --nodiscover --datadir ~/.ethereum/privateconsortium --unlock 79d4107bce40f988e25b6db92dc8ebxxxxxx8062 --mine --rpc --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpcapi eth,net,web3,personal,admin --networkid 9876`

Answer (score 1):

You must run at least 2 nodes, then your private network will work

Clique blockchain works 50%+1 node, min 2